# Can I use assumptions to declare a variable's type?

Tags: vector, assumptions

I'm trying to declare $P$ as a vector. I searched for a while, the closest way seems to be `Assumptions`:

```
$Assumptions = P \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]
```

But what does it really do? For example:

```
$Assumptions = P \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]
P == {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Just return $P = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. If $P$ is a 3D vector, it can't be a 4D vector at the same time, right? Why doesn't it return false?

I'm very new to Mathematica and I don't know what it can or can't do. Please bear with me if my question makes no sense.

Comment: This may be difficult in general. Why are you trying to declare P as a vector? In other words ,what other operations downstream of that declaration would you like to carry out that depend on that property of P?

Comment: @MarcoB I'm trying to prove `Norm[P+Q] <= Norm[P] + Norm[Q]`

Comment: I think proving preorder theorems like this is not possible now — you'll need a proof assistant for this with the axioms (like Coq/Agda etc)

The general case is to use FullSimplify and hope it will answer True, but this will not work for such general expressions. Anyway it will not give you a proof.

There's some support for equational theorem proving in the form of FindEquationalProof and that's all.

Comment: @PavelPerikov Oh, sorry, I didn't make it clear. I'm not trying to "formally prove" it (like in Coq). I'm just manually writing down the proof, and I hope Mathematicas knows how to expand my statements, for example expanding `Norm[P]` to `Sqrt[Sum[P[i], {i,1,3}]]` or something

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan, Oh, I see. I still sure it's not possible in general but you can check for specific sizes (like 10 here): `Block[{a, vec}, vec = Array[Indexed[a, #] &, 10]; 
 Simplify[Norm@vec == Sqrt@Total@(vec^2), vec \[Element] Reals]]`

Comment: `$Assumptions` are only used by functions that take the option `Assumptions`. Since `Equal` does not take options, you must add `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to have the `$Assumptions` used. Then `P == {1, 2, 3, 4} // Simplify` evaluates to `False`

Comment: Thank you both very much!